# Sed replace regex pattern with nothing

Tags: text-processing, sed

Hey so I want to replace a regex pattern with nothing, I've tried multiple sed routes but none seem to be working, i.e

```
sed -i 's/\.\d{1,3}\b$//'
```

Example of input,

```
Hello.123
Hello.123.90
```

expected output would be,

```
Hello
Hello.123
```

Comment: So what are you trying to match? You've shown us a regex that does not do what you want, but you haven't explained what you need. Are you trying to remove the last `.` followed by 1 to 3 numbers from each line? What if a line is `foo.1234`? Should we leave that unchanged?

Comment: Yes I want to remove the last dot followed by 1 to 3 numbers from each line.

Comment: OK, so what happens with `foo.1234`? Nothing? Do we just print the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe yo can try  something like this:

```
sed -i -E 's/\.[0-9]{1,3}$//' file
```

Comment: thank you for your help